# GDB on Mac stepping into the function

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, gdb, homebrew

GDB debugging on Mac throws warning below and does not allow to step inside a function.

```
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libsystem_kernel.a"
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/_libc_funcptr.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory. 
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kernel_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory. 
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/memcpy.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory. 
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strcmp.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory. 
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strlcpy.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory. 
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strlen.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory. 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libatomics_normal.a" 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libcachecontrol_normal.a" 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libos_normal.a" 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libsetjmp_normal.a" 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libsimple_normal.a" 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libstring_normal.a" 
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libucontext_normal.a" 
warning: `/private/var/tmp/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/libplatform.build/libsystem_platform.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/init.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

This is on a Mavericks Mac with gcc as an llvm build 
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

and gdb is installed through homebrew.
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9

I have codesigned gdb but still the problem persists.